# How to execute a method and return a value for a lunar calendar conversion class snippet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar

The comment from the creator below has suggested to instantiate the class method with
CNCalendar.CNDate cd = new CNCalendar.CNDate();
but it is giving me error under visual studio returning

'MvcApplication03262014b.Models.CNCalendar.CNDate()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

can anyone give me some pointers on how to use this class method snippet? thanks

---

original creator of the snippets has added some comments within their code with suggestion on how to use the class method

```
    // 一些使用的範例程式
    //for (int i = 2007; i <= 2050; i++)
    //{
    //    CNCalendar.CNDate cd1 = new CNCalendar.CNDate(new DateTime(i, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day));
    //    Response.Write("計算 " + i + "年隔年農曆過年的國曆日期：" + cd1.GetNextLunarNewYearDate().ToLongDateString() + "<br/>");
    //}

    //CNCalendar.CNDate cd = new CNCalendar.CNDate();

    //Response.Write("今年農曆天數：" + cd.LunarYearDays(2007).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 01 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 1).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 02 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 2).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 03 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 3).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 04 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 4).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 05 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 5).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 06 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 6).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 07 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 7).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 08 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 8).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 09 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 9).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 10 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 10).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 11 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 11).ToString() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年 12 月農曆天數：" + cd.LunarMonthDays(2007, 12).ToString() + "<br/>");

    //Response.Write("今天的農曆日期：" + cd.GetLunarHolDay() + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("今年的農曆潤月月份：" + cd.GetLeapMonth(2007) + "<br/>");
    //Response.Write("計算國曆當天對應的節氣：" + cd.l_GetLunarHolDay() + "<br/>");

    //Response.Write("計算今年農曆過年的國曆日期：" + cd.GetLunarNewYearDate().ToLongDateString() + "<br/>");
```

Comment: What's the return type of method `CNDate()`? Is `CNCalendar` a namespace or a class?

Comment: May I ask why don't you use standard [ChineseLunisolarCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.chineselunisolarcalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: CNCalendar is the class name, and namespace is just a random auto generated name for the project.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the ChineseLunisolarCalendar,  I have ran into that and considered using it,  but is the class method or .Net 4.5 free to port? if I port away from Microsoft.   basically for ease of porting and licensing.   not likely but there is a good chance I may want to port to mobile platform  or use with mono in the future.

Comment: @Bigs Looks like it is supported on [Mono](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Globalization.ChineseLunisolarCalendar%2fM)